# IIS10 giving back a 401 for a svc/wcf api

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10

Hi we have a web application that communicates to another web application using an wcf/svc API.

This seems to work ok, however everyday the wcf/svc API despite actioning the request and sending the correct information back, marks it as a 401 (we can see this in fiddler)

In order to make the service return the correct 200 response we do an iisreset which normally after one or two goes makes the server play ball for another day. We have tried to automate the iisreset but to no avail.

Our Server Guys want to reinstall HTTP Activation feature we have a few other ideas as well.
But at the moment it's like trying to hunt for a needle in a haystack.

Any ideas out there.

At the moment when I've googled this problem I just see a lot of old issues for older versions of iis/our server.
e.g
http://aadhoc.blogspot.com/2010/01/wcf-service-401-intermittent-error.html

### **Update**

There are 2 severs which are load balanced - seems that normally only the one throws a wobbly every day.

**

### Update 2

Got the failed request tracing logs back and they say Authentication "NOT_AVAILABLE"

Comment: what are the sub codes in the W3 Logs for these requests? 401.xx?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf unfortunatly I just get back
- 443 - 10.197.104.32 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.42000) - 401 1 2148074254 15
So doesn't say...

Comment: @PeterHahndorf in fact it's more like this
- 10.197.104.11 - - 401 0 0 127

Comment: You have to be very carefully locating the right lines in IIS log files and then determine what exactly is the sub status code you will focus on. If 401.0, then FRT might lead you further to the right component to investigate https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thanks yeah id read about that failed request tracing and could be the next place to look at.... Thanks

Comment: @PeterHahndorf thanks for the suggestions I've posted an update the error is Authentication NOT_AVAILABLE any ideas?

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the suggestions I've posted an update the error is Authentication NOT_AVAILABLE any ideas?